# Confusing navigation between facebook. -> meta -> and "main"

Tags: discussion, navigation, header, mini-site

When I'm on facebook.stackoverflow.com and click on the 'meta' link in the header, I'm taken to the meta site.  But when I then click on the 'main' link in the header I'm taken to Stack Overflow proper instead back to the facebook. subdomain.  From meta, I cannot find a way to link back to the mini-site.

I'm sure this would be a PITA to implement properly, but I just thought I would bring it up as a possible source of UX confusion in case there was in fact something that could be done to prevent this confusion.

Comment: A Return Url parameter in the link would solve it nicely, and would not be that difficult to implement.